# MPMoviePlayerController doesn't work after upgrading to iOS 5

Tags: mpmovieplayercontroller, ios5

This code works perfectly on iPad 4.3 Simulator:

```
NSString *source = [mediaObject objectForKey:@"source"];
NSString *videoPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", path, source];
NSURL *videoUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:videoPath];

MPMoviePlayerController *videoPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoUrl];
videoPlayer.shouldAutoplay = NO;

videoPlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(xPos, yPos, width, height);

[backgroundImageView addSubview:videoPlayer.view];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(videoPlaybackStateDidChange:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification object:videoPlayer];
```

but it doesn't work on iPad 5 Simulator. I get a black frame with no movie nor playback controls.

I read the Apple changelog about MPMoviePlayerController, but I didn't found anything about this problem. Can you help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved the problem in this way: in my header file I wrote:

```
MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer;
```

with this property:

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer;
```

and in the method in which I init the moviePlayer:

```
MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieUrl];
self.moviePlayer = player;
```

It seems that assigning the player to a property "saves" the player. But don't ask me why...

Comment: Thanks. I spent a couple of hours trying to figure this one out. Someone with a deeper understanding of ARC might want to weigh in why this needs to be a property to stay alive.

Comment: You need a property so the view controller is being retained - just because the backgroundImageView retains its view doesn't make it retain the view controller.

Answer (score 2):

You don't mention what type of URL you are trying to play, however, if it's an HTTP Live Streaming resource (.m3u8 file), then be aware that iOS 5.0 seems to have tightened up on validating the contents of the m3u8 index file.

Specifically, I've discovered that:

1. No individual segment can be more than twice as long as the `#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION` value;
2. The `#EXTINF` value (segment length in seconds) can, now, only be an integer value.

If one of these is your problem, running your application under the iOS 5.0 simulator should show a warning in the debugger console.

Comment: Hello. The video is a simple .mp4 file, located in a subfolder of "Documents" app folder.

Comment: The problem exists also on the real device.

Comment: @Martin Kenny: i have posted a similar question can you look into it. [LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7912653/encrypted-live-stream-does-not-work-in-ios5-but-works-in-ios4)

Answer (score 1):

For HLS on iOS5, the TARGETDURATION value is really not the target duration but needs to be the maximum duration. So it should be set to the largest segment in the file.