# Encrypted Live stream does not play in IOS5 but plays in IOS4

Tags: ios, streaming, ios5, http-live-streaming

basically the below shown segmented video files playlist **plays fine in IOS4** but not in IOS5, so i guess that there is no error in the encoding, segmenting or the encryption.

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:10
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:1
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="http://xxx.xx.x.xx/ios/keys/key.txt",IV=0x00000000000000000000000000000000
#EXTINF:10,
http://xxx.xx.x.xx/ios/myvideo/stream-1.ts
#EXTINF:10,
http://xxx.xx.x.xx/ios/myvideo/stream-2.ts

...

#EXTINF:10,
http://xxx.xx.x.xx/ios/myvideo/stream-502.ts
#EXTINF:10,
http://xxx.xx.x.xx/ios/myvideo/stream-503.ts
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

the error is a blunt **'The operation could not be completed'** in the safari. but the same list plays fine if the files are not encrypted is both OS versions.

This **[thread](http://www.wowza.com/forums/showthread.php?15282-Issues-with-iOS5-%28iPad%29-and-VOD-%28Cupertino%29)** seems to discuss a similar issue but the solution is closed to public.

i also came across this **[thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7796329/mpmovieplayercontroller-doesnt-work-after-upgrading-to-ios-5/7808542#7808542)** which suggests it is related to the `#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION` tag but i cannot make out much about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the docs [here](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-pantos-http-live-streaming-07#page-8) the IV tag is optional and [this](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-pantos-http-live-streaming-07#section-5.2) explains that sequence no should be used as IV while decryption if IV is missing.

the problem IOS4 and IOS5 handles them differently

so this works for IOS5, but threw error in IOS4

```
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="http://xxx.xx.x.xx/ios/keys/key.txt"
```

while this works for IOS4, but throws error in IOS5

```
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="http://xxx.xx.x.xx/ios/keys/key.txt",IV=0x00000000000000000000000000000000
```

in my case.

Answer (score 0):

For HLS on iOS5, the TARGETDURATION value is really not the target duration but needs to be the maximum duration. So it should be set to the largest segment in the file.